# Using Array.map in Angular Interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Using Angular 2+, how can I do something like bellow in the HTML?

```
{{ object.array.map( (o)=> o.property ) }}
```

This code crashes the angular application. I have to use Pipe or something like that?

Comment: Make a function for that in your typescript code and call that function instead? Not sure if that's exactly what you're trying to do though

Comment: Im just trying to do the 'Array.map' function in the HTML.

Comment: You can't. Do it when your `object.array` arrives in the component.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't define functions in Angular expressions. So you have to use *pipes* instead which are optimized for the templates. They are reusable across other components.

```
<pre>{{ object.array | pluck:"property" | json }}</pre>
```

With a pluck pipe:

```js
@Pipe({name: 'pluck'})
export class PluckPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform (input: any[], key: string): any {
      return input.map(value => value[key]);
  }
}
```

It's not recommended to call functions on the component to calculate values for the template. This *moves* work from the component to the template, and if you need data to be *mutated* then do that work in `ngOnInit()` or in `ngOnChanges()` instead.

Pipes have *purity* which means they are executed only when the inbound data is *mutated*. When you call a function like `{{doWork(object.array)}}` then Angular does not know if the function `doWork()` is *pure* or not. So it assumes it is not pure and calls it for each change detection.

**Updated:**

Anytime you work with Arrays in Angular you should be treating them as immutable. Where you create a new instance of that Array when you need to modify it. For example; `items = [...items, newItem];` instead of `items.push(newItems)`.

This resolves change detection problems related to pipes, ngFor, OnPush change detection and state stores.

https://medium.com/dailyjs/the-state-of-immutability-169d2cd11310

Comment: yes, but making this pipe "pure" means that you must change the array reference everytime a member is changed in order to accurately reflect the model. methods like push and splice can't be used safely, nor can mutating an item in the array.  This is non transparent and could lead to weird or hard to understand bugs.

Comment: non transparent immutability is absolutely a source of bugs.

Comment: @bryan60 anyway, I understand what you're saying. I just don't think it's related to the OPs question. It's a longer discussion.

Comment: perhaps it is, but your answer to OP's question should mention that this carries a dependency (or shortcoming) on treating your array as immutable if using this pipe, as it may be non obvious.

Comment: @bryan60 answer has been updated. Thank you for your feedback. Sorry for being prickly about it.

Answer (score 5):

you could find some work around's to make this work, but my answer is you shouldn't do this as function calls in template negatively impact performance, as do impure pipes which this would require to be reliable.

Consider instead:

```
mappedArray = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.mappedArray = object.array.map( (o)=> o.property );
}

{{ mappedArray }}
```

clean, reliable, easy to read / modify and easy to understand. Also gives more fine tuned control over when your functions evaluate.

Comment:  this consider the best solution in this case 

Comment: What if the content of `object.array` is modified later?

Comment: @ConnorsFan then it is important to ensure in your controller that the map function is re run in those cases. The point is to have fine control over when this occurs as to not become a performance drag and for the component to operate in a clear and transparent manner.

Answer (score 2):

you can just create a get property and use it like this

*component*

```
   data = [
     {property : 'a'},
     {property : 'b'},
     {property : 'c'},
     ]

  get properties () {
    return this.data.map( (o)=> o.property )
  }
```

template

```
{{properties | json}}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qp9wqu)

Comment: Thanks - best answer imo. Quick and easy to implement and it works

Answer (score 1):

In your **component**, you can have a function:

```
someFunction(arr: any[]){
    return arr.map(o => o.property);
}
```

And in your html **template**, assuming `arr` is some defined array already, you can simply just call that function where you want the array to be used. Example:

```
<div *ngFor="let object of someFunction(arr)>
    {{object.property}}
</div>
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to directly invoke code like that directly in the html template without some use of functions.

*it is also worth noting this code is not very optimized because `someFunction()` will be repeatedly getting called over and over again due to where it exists in the template.

Comment: you canot invoke `array.map()` directly in html using Angular